# Using "+=" when "+" is overloaded in a class function?

Tags: c++, function, class, overloading, operator-keyword

```
const function operator+(const function *) const;
```

What will happen if you do: `x += y;` ...when x and y are of the same class. Does it still work in this context or does it have to be `x + y;`?

Comment: Nothing will happen unless you overload `+=` for your class. Also, your `+` operator will probably not work, because it expects a pointer on the RHS.

Answer (score 3):

In order for `+=` to work for a user defined type, it has to be overloaded. This is independent of whether `operator+` has already been overloaded for that type. There is no automatic generation of arithmetic operators based on other ones<sup>1</sup>.

Note that the usual strategy is to overload `operator+` as a non-member, in terms of `operator +=`. For example,

```
struct Foo
{
  int i;
  Foo& operator += (const Foo& rhs) 
  { 
    i += rhs.i; 
    return *this;
  }
};

Foo operator+(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs)
{
  Foo result = lhs;
  result += rhs;
  return result;
}
```

**Note**: The latter operator is often expressed as a one or two-liner (see for example SO's own [*operator overloading wiki*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719). But that inhibits *return value optimization* for little gain. I have chosen a more verbose implementation here to avoid that pitfall, without incurring any loss in clarity.

---

<sup>1 Attempts at solving this "problem" are [`boost operators`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) and the broken [`std::rel_ops`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

They are distinct and unrelated (as far as compiler is concerned)

Though, if you overload 1 of them, it is probably worth also overloading the other for consistency

btw. Here is very good explanation of operator overloadings:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/3595112

Comment: Unfortunately the `operator+=` implementation in the operators wiki is sub-optimal. I may change it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support `+=`, you need to overload `operator+=` to do so. Just overloading `+` and/or `=` is not sufficient.

[Boost operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/utility/operators.htm) does support this though. Basically, you provide overloads of a very minimal set of operators, and it fills in the holes using those.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work, and end up in error. If you want to make `+=` to work, you'll need to overload that operator too, overloading `+` only isn't enough.